# pyqt wait all qthread to finish and then do something

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, queue

how wait all threads and queue to finsh and then do something

modules i used

```
from multiprocessing import queues
Qthread
```

code of method

```
  def process(self):
        scan_thread_num = int(main.ui.scan_thread_input.text()) + 1
        self.scan_threads = []
        for i in range(1, scan_thread_num):
             scan_thread = Qthread(self.scan_queue)
             self.scan_threads.append(scan_thread)
             scan_thread.trigger.connect(self.addto_scan_list)
             scan_thread.start()

        for i in range(1, 2000):  
            self.scan_queue.put(i)
```